# rsyslog: store & forward logs that have been forwarded to this server

Tags: store, syslog, forward, rsyslog

What I want to do is covered here almost exactly: https://scubarda.com/2015/11/06/rsyslog-store-and-forward-messages-to-other-hosts/

There is one issue however, which is that it suggests

```
$template RemoteHost,"/var/spool/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/syslog.log"
```

to first store the logs locally. However I'm already storing locally with a series of directives like:

```
:HOSTNAME, isequal, "netdevice01" /var/log/network.log
& ~
:HOSTNAME, isequal, "netdevice02" /var/log/network.log
& ~
```

etc. and I want to keep those that way. I only want logs from those devices to go into this one file and also get forwarded. When I use the `$template RemoteHost,"/var/spool/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/syslog.log"` it stops logging to my /var/log/network.log and instead stores everything (including logs from other servers) in those new ones.

Can anyone suggest how to keep everything in /var/log/network.log the way it is now but also forward these to the remote syslog server?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how this works, the template is used on your central server, not the remote server. You use that template to build the log path from messages coming in from remote machines

Comment: @Rumbles thanks and sorry I didn't see your reply til now. Yes I am receiving messages on a "central" server and receiving them from remote machines but I ALSO want to forward them (after storing on the central). Much like what is being done in the link I included.

Eventually I was able to do what I wanted with the following:

`if $fromhost startswith ['host1','host2',host3']  then {
*.warn  action(type="omfwd" target="1.2.3.4" port="514" protocol="udp"
            action.resumeRetryCount="100"
            queue.type="linkedList" queue.size="10000")
}`